# Bigcommerce: Can_modify field in Cart.yml

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

In bigcommerce we have this content.html we have this code for the x(close) button in the cart page:

```
{{#or can_modify (if type '==' 'GiftCertificate')}}
                        <button class="cart-remove icon"
                                data-cart-itemid="{{id}}"
                                data-confirm-delete="{{lang 'cart.confirm_delete'}}"
                                aria-label="{{lang 'cart.remove_item' name=name}}"
                        >
                            <svg><use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use></svg>
                        </button>
                    {{/or}}
```

Some products doesnt have the close button in it and I wonder where can I set the can_modify variable as it seems it is the reason. Any thoughts?

Comment: this doesn't look like stenciljs, why its having stenciljs tag?

Comment: Ok ill remove it, i tag the wrong item

Answer (score 0):

The can_modify conditional was added to Cornerstone 7 years ago in a commit titled "[Hide modify buttons for child products](https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/commit/ff2971c249d71b4e06dc6334eab0bbdda034310b)". However, I have worked on hundreds of BigCommerce sites, and I have no idea what it means by "child products". As far as I know, any line item should be removable from the cart, at least in the new products V3 setup. Looking at the can_modify property in the [cart stencil object doc](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/theme-objects/c2NoOjg3NzQ5MDc-cart), it appears there is no info on this.

I would argue that the can_modify property is deprecated, and can essentially be ignored. There is no way to control it from the admin, and it is not a property that can be adjusted via the [cart API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/b3A6MzU5MDQxOTY-update-cart-line-item).

In conclusion, I would say if you want the remove button to appear on every item in the cart, simply delete the conditional altogether.

I will separately open an issue on the Cornerstone repository to ask about this item!